# class is implementing runnable interface but not defining the run method

Tags: java, multithreading

```
class Qus3 extends Thread implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Qus3 q3 = new Qus3();
        q3.start();
    }
}
```

This code compiles without any error but isn't it necessary to define all the methods 
of an interface otherwise declare the class abstract.In the above code Class hasn't been declared abstract and run() is also not defined by the class although it has implemented Runnable interface, why the code is still correct?

Comment: that's because it extends Thread which has run()

Comment: Also `Thread` implements `Runnable`, so your code would not be any different if you omit `implements Runnable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class implements Runnable but also extends Thread. Internally Thread also implements Runnable and provides implementation for it. That is the reason it compiles successfully.

If you **remove `extends Thread`**, you will see it will give compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

Thread implements Runnable. [from the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html):

> public void run()
>
> If this thread was constructed using a separate Runnable run object,
>   then that Runnable object's run method is called; otherwise, this
>   method does nothing and returns.
>
> Subclasses of Thread should override this method.

So you won't get a compile error, but `run` won't do anything. The newly-started thread will execute the empty run method and terminate.

Your code is correct, but it's a better idea to avoid extending Thread, create a separate Runnable and pass that in to the new thread. That way not only can you extend something other than Thread, but you won't risk accidentally overriding thread methods.

Answer (score 1):

Thread overrides run, since you extend Thread, your run method is implemented.